# How to create custom operators in cython?

Tags: python, cython, ctypes, cythonize

How to create a custom operator in cython? Here is c++ code for creating simple + operator.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vector3
    {
        private:
                float x, y, z;
            
        public:
                Vector3(float x = 0, float y = 0, float z = 0)
                {
                    this->x = x;
                    this->y = y;
                    this->z = z;
                }

                Vector3 operator + (Vector3 const &obj)
                {
                    Vector3 result;
                    result.x = x + obj.x;
                    result.y = y + obj.y;
                    result.z = z + obj.z;
                    return result;
                }

                void show()
                {
                    cout << "Vector(" << x << "," << y << "," << z << ")";
                }
    };
int main()
{
    Vector3 v1(1,1,1), v2(2,2,2);
    Vector3 v3 = v1 + v2;
    v3.show();
}
```

I know we can create wrapper for this c++ file, I would like to know doing this in cython natively without using c++.

Comment: Implement `__add__` in your class definition?

Comment: @JohnColeman will that affect performance?

Comment: I don't see why it should, but I don't really know cython rather than python.

Comment: __add__() can only defined using 'def' not 'cdef' which means it is pythonic, so it could be slow i guess. Any way i'll try that.

Comment: Arithmetic operators end up defined in a fairly efficient way. Don't get too hung up on it being `def` rather than `cdef`. In any case it's kind of your only option